# Find $|M|$, where $M = \{x \in \mathbb{R}\ |\ 3^{x+3}+9=\sqrt{81^{2x-1}}+3^{4x}\}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

> Find $|M|$, where $M = \left \{x \in \mathbb{R}\ |\ 3^{x+3} + 9 = \sqrt{81^{2x-1}} + 3^{4x} \right \}$

This is a problem from my homework, and although I think I know how to start, I get stuck. Here's what I tried:

$$
\begin{align}
3^{x+3} + 9 &= \sqrt{81^{2x-1}}+3^{4x} \\
\iff 27\cdot 3^{x}+9 &= \sqrt{\frac{(3^{x})^{8}}{3^4}}+(3^{x})^4 \\
\end{align}
$$
Let $t = 3^x$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
& \iff 27t + 9 = \frac{1}{9}t^4+t^4 \\
& \iff \frac{10}{9}t^4-27t-9 = 0 \\
\end{align}
$$

Here, I do not know how to find the solutions of the equation. Is there a general way to factorize such polynomials? Or perhaps this is not the right approach for this problem?

Comment: Yes, there are algorithms for factorisations of integer polynomials. Here we obtain $10t^4-9\cdot 27t-81=(10t^3 + 30t^2 + 90t + 27)(t - 3)$ by the Rational Root Theorem.

Comment: You can use Descartes law of signs to estimate the number of real root solutions, and rational root theorem to find possible evident solutions (in this case should divide constant coeff $81$, it happens that $3$ is a root). Note: $t>0$.